# What's the anime where a girl who comes to town to fight an enemy meets a guy who lives with an old man? (It's not Bleach)

Tags: story-identification, anime

I vaguely remember parts of it, and I'm not sure about the exact details, but something along the lines of:

- the guy(MC I think ) is an orphan but lives with an old man who teases him (in a monastery?)
- the girl has long black(?) hair with bangs, has a sword, is part of an organization(?)
- she remembers in a flashback how an old woman once told her when she was a child that she'd find someone someday who'd love her to death
- anyway she came to town to fight this great evil(a demon?)
- fighting in general happens by grid and on rooftops
- they meet somehow after a fight & she kinda falls in love?
- she thinks it's this guy who's her soulmate & she doesn't wanna lose him
- later something happened and she willingly went to fight this enemy alone, who ended up taking control of her
- one particular scene goes like this: the main character goes looking for her & ends up finding her with her eyes glowing purple, there was lightning in the background...she tells him to go back & there's nothing he can do or something like that

That's all I can remember. I saw it 8 or 9 years ago. Please, this anime has been bugging me a lot lately, and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Was the setting modern day or historical?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure but i can think of two possibilities:

[***Omamori himari***](https://myanimelist.net/anime/6324/Omamori_Himari)

[image: Omamori Himari]

It matches the black haired girl with a sword, the orphan MC and the demons plot. since i haven't watched it i can't tell if the part of "destined love" is there.

[***Isuca***](https://myanimelist.net/anime/25429/Isuca)

[image: Isuca]

It doesn't match the hair color nor the weapon but the demons, the orphan and the "destined one" part kinda does (he has the ability to see true names and can control anybody on the spiritual world, so the girl family wants him to marry her)

hope it helps!